# How can I automatically change the CSS min-height value of a div when a JavaScript is performed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

I am absolutely new in JavaScript and jQuery and I have the following problem. In a page I have this div having **id="treeFormContainer"**

```
<div id="treeFormContainer">
    <table id="aui_3_2_0_1108" width="100%" border="0">
        <tbody id="aui_3_2_0_1107">
            <tr id="aui_3_2_0_1106">
                <td id="leftColumn" width="33.3%">
                    <!-- SHOW SOMETHING  -->
                </td>

                <td id="rightColumn" width="66.6%">
                    <!-- SHOW SOMETHING  -->
                    <div id="wwctrl_submitEventButton" align="right">
                        <input id="submitEventButton" type="submit" onclick="return clickSubmitButton();" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And the following CSS related to this div:

```
#treeFormContainer {
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

As you can see in the previous table, into the second column it is show an **submit input tag**, this one:

```
<input id="submitEventButton" 
       type="submit" 
       onclick="return clickSubmitButton();" 
       value="Submit">
```

When the user click on this button it is performed this JavaScript method:

```
function validateForm() {
    var selectedProjectStatus = document.getElementById("selectStatus");
    var indexSelectedStatus = selectedProjectStatus.selectedIndex;

    var selectedProjectStatusText = selectedProjectStatus.options[selectedProjectStatus.selectedIndex].text;

    // VALIDAZIONE DEL PROJECT NAME:
    if( document.getElementById('kmProjectInfo_name').value == "" )
    {
        alert( "Please provide a valid project name" );
        //document.myForm.Name.focus();
        document.getElementById('kmProjectInfo_name').focus();
        return false;
    }

    //............................................................
    //............................................................
    //............................................................

    return false;

}
```

This script only performs some validations to some field of a form not showed in the previous HTML code snippet.

I want to do the following thing:

when the script is performed the CSS **min-height: 200px;** of the div having **id=treeFormContainer** is automatically changed to **min-height: 50px;**

How can I do it?

Comment: how is clickSubmitButton executing validateForm() ? also, since it is a submit button it most likely will refresh your page, unless you prevent the event... But it doesn't seems to be the case. Even if you will change the css, therefore, the page will still be refreshed. Perhaps you first want to change that submit button to a regular button? (then apply css rules onclick, check and later submit..?) (also, where is your <form> tag refering to the submit button?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submitEventButton").click(function(){
    //here is the line you want
    $("#treeFormContainer").css("min-height","50px");
    var indexSelectedStatus = $("#selectStatus").val();
    var selectedProjectStatusText = $("#selectStatus").text();
    if($('#kmProjectInfo_name').val() == "" )
    {
        alert( "Please provide a valid project name" );
        //document.myForm.Name.focus();
        $('#kmProjectInfo_name').focus();
        return false;
    }
    //............................................................
    //............................................................
    //............................................................
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to just change the min-height of the `treeFormContainer` div, so it's pretty easy using the css method of jquery.

Here's some useful documentation on JQuery: http://api.jquery.com/css/

```
$("#treeFormContainer).css("min-height", "50px");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or without using jQuery

```
document.getElementById('treeFormContainer').style.minHeight = '50px';
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0e193mc/) for your reference